# Improving speed and simplify code of "leetcode" Roman Numbers converter

Tags: c++, performance, roman-numerals

I just have the free account at leetcode. I've been practicing some coding there in preparation for interviews. But I can't see the solution logic behind the `IntegerToRoman` conversion function. I solved both the leetcode Roman Numbers problems (Arabic -> roman, and roman -> Arabic). I made a solution of my own but its slower than most accepted leetcode solutions.

I would appreciate any feedback code review-wise on the solutions but the main goal is to make them faster somehow. Especially the `IntToRoman` seemed trickier when I got to coding it. The `RomanToInt` was tricky as well, but when I realized the reversal it seemed OK. I started to code it with a stack originally instead of the oldval, but variable is enough and stack isn't needed as such.

The main code:

```
int fasterRomanToInt(std::string s)
{
    int romanSum{ 0 };
    if (s.size() == 1)
    {
        return oneSizeRomans(s[0]);
    }
    else
    {
        int oldval = 0;
        int i = s.length() - 1;
        while (i >= 0)
        {
            char current = s[i];
            int curval = oneSizeRomans(current);
            if (curval >= oldval)
            {
                romanSum += curval;
            }
            else
            {
                romanSum -= curval;
            }
            oldval = curval;
            --i;
        }
        return romanSum;
    }
}


std::string intToRoman(int num)
{
    std::map<int, std::string> ArabicvalueToRomans
    {
        {1000, "M"},
        {900, "CM"},
        {500, "D"},
        {400, "CD"},
        {100, "C"},
        {90, "XC"},
        {50, "L"},
        {40, "XL"},
        {10, "X"},
        {9, "IX"},
        {8, "VIII"},
        {7, "VII"},
        {6, "VI"},
        {5, "V"},
        {4, "IV"},
        {3, "III"},
        {2, "II"},
        {1, "I"}
    };

    std::vector<int> romanSpecials{ 1000, 900, 500, 400, 100, 90, 50, 40, 10, 9, 8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1 };

    int arabic = num;
    std::string result = "";
    while (arabic > 0)
    {
        int d = seekLargestPossible(romanSpecials, arabic);
        int r = arabic % d;
        std::string characters = processToRoman(d, ArabicvalueToRomans);
        arabic -= d;
        result += characters;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Here's a couple helper functions for `intToRoman`:

```
int seekLargestPossible(std::vector<int>& vecRef, int a)
{

    // input bigger than biggest divisor so use 1000
    if (a >= 1000)
    {
        return 1000;
    }



    // seek the biggest divisor that is smallerorequal than the A inputvalue
    
    for (auto iter = vecRef.begin(); iter != vecRef.end(); iter++)
    {
        auto key = *(iter);
        if (key <= a)
        {
            return key;
        }
    }
    throw "something went bad in seekLargestPossible";
}

    std::string processToRoman(int value, std::map<int, std::string>& mapRef)
{
    // if cannot access romanstr in map with key, throws which is good
    // shuldnt be happening tho
    std::string s = mapRef.at(value);
    return s;
}
```

And here's a helper function for `RomanToInt`:

```
int oneSizeRomans(char c)
{
    /*  I             1
        V             5
        X             10
        L             50
        C             100
        D             500
        M             1000*/
    switch (c)
    {
    case 'I': return 1;
    case 'V': return 5;
    case 'X': return 10;
    case 'L': return 50;
    case 'C':return 100;
    case 'D':return 500;
    case 'M':return 1000;

    default:
        throw "bad things one size romans func";
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: `std::map` is slow unless your benchmark shows it to be faster than say `std::vector`. Only ever use it where it performs better, or when it makes code simpler but the performance hit doesn't matter much. For small maps that would fit into a couple of cache lines if they were a vector, the vector always wins: less page misses, less data cache misses, less code cache misses since the code is smaller, less branch mispredictions.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of minor things that haven't been pointed out explicitly elsewhere:

### copying strings is slow

`int fasterRomanToInt(std::string s)` This copies a string.

It's possible that the string is short enough that this copy doesn't involve memory allocation. It's also possible that we're moving from the input string, so that it becomes just a copy of a pointer and size. But we can't count on either of those things.

So we should pass the `std::string` by reference, or instead pass a `std::string_view` (effectively just a pointer and a size) by value:

```
int fasterRomanToInt(std::string const& s)
int fasterRomanToInt(std::string_view sv)
```

Note that you can change the function signature in LeetCode's `class Solution` too!

---

### use (reverse) iterators for iteration:

The overall algorithm for `romanToInt` looks decent, but it could be presented more neatly.

For example, we can iterate backwards through a `std::string` (or `std::string_view`) using reverse iterators:

```
constexpr int roman_to_int(std::string_view sv)
{
    auto total = 0;
    auto prev = 0;
    
    for (auto c = sv.rbegin(); c != sv.rend(); ++c)
    {
        auto value = get_roman_value(*c); // switch statement...
        total += (value >= prev) ? value : -value;
        prev = value;
    }
    
    return total;
}
```

---

### avoid extra work:

```
while (arabic > 0)
{
    int d = seekLargestPossible(romanSpecials, arabic);
    int r = arabic % d;
    std::string characters = processToRoman(d, ArabicvalueToRomans);
    arabic -= d;
    result += characters;
}
```

`seekLargestPossible` searches the entire map every loop. Note that once we've dealt with the largest value, the next one must be equal or smaller, so we can search a smaller subset.

`r` appears to be unused! (I'm guessing you were going to create a repeating string where necessary - note however, that only 1 values are repeated, and only up to 3 times, so perhaps there's not much point in doing an extra division, compared to simply continuing with the loop).

### write the simplest possible code first:

Given the very restricted set of inputs, and the fact that the next number we deal with is always smaller, we could write everything out long-hand:

```
std::string int_to_roman(int num)
{
    assert(num > 0);
    assert(num <= 3999);
    
    auto out = std::string();
    
    for (; num >= 1000; num -= 1000) { out += 'M'; }
    
    if (num >= 900) { num -= 900; out += "CM"; }
    if (num >= 500) { num -= 500; out += 'D'; }
    if (num >= 400) { num -= 400; out += "CD"; }
    for (; num >= 100; num -= 100) { out += 'C'; }
    
    if (num >= 90) { num -= 90; out += "XC"; }
    if (num >= 50) { num -= 50; out += 'L'; }
    if (num >= 40) { num -= 40; out += "XL"; }
    for (; num >= 10; num -= 10) { out += 'X'; }
    
    if (num >= 9) { num -= 9; out += "IX"; }
    if (num >= 5) { num -= 5; out += 'V'; }
    if (num >= 4) { num -= 4; out += "IV"; }
    for (; num >= 1; num -= 1) { out += 'I'; }
    
    return out;
}
```

And... this is probably fast enough ("0ms" according to leetcode)! We could of course factor out the obvious grouping pattern of N * (9, 5, 4, 1), but there's not really any need (and we actually have to be careful to avoid making it slower).

Another (perhaps even simpler) approach is to notice that we're still dealing with a decimal system, and we don't have to care at all about the logic of how the characters are calculated! We can get them directly from a size-10 lookup table:

```
using chars_t = std::array<std::string_view, 10>;
auto static constexpr thousands = chars_t{ "M", "MM", "MMM", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_" };
auto static constexpr hundreds = chars_t{ "C", "CC", "CCC", "CD", "D", "DC", "DCC", "DCCC", "CM" };
auto static constexpr tens = chars_t{ "X", "XX", "XXX", "XL", "L", "LX", "LXX", "LXXX", "XC" };
auto static constexpr ones = chars_t{ "I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", "VII", "VIII", "IX" };

std::string int_to_roman(int num)
{
    assert(num >= 1);
    assert(num <= 3999);
    
    auto out = std::string();
    
    if (num >= 1000) { auto const index = num / 1000; num -= index * 1000; out += thousands[index-1]; }
    if (num >= 100)  { auto const index = num / 100;  num -= index * 100;  out += hundreds[index-1]; }
    if (num >= 10)   { auto const index = num / 10;   num -= index * 10;   out += tens[index-1]; }
    if (num >= 1)    { auto const index = num / 1;    num -= index * 1;    out += ones[index-1]; }
    
    return out;
}
```

Again, this is super fast (I suspect faster).

Answer (score 2):

```
if (s.size() == 1)
{
    return oneSizeRomans(s[0]);
}
```

There is nothing special with a size of 1. Yes, you can return early of course, but *all the other values* will have to go through this spurious `if` statement as well.

If well programmed you could even get away with a length of *zero* (hint)!

---

```
int i = s.length() - 1;
while (i >= 0)
```

What's wrong with a `for` loop? I'm not sure if this makes any difference when a smart compiler handles things, but I am pretty sure that the `for` won't be *slower*.

---

```
int curval = oneSizeRomans(current);
```

Note that calling methods always has a performance penalty. You could use a macro or inline call instead. Or you could actually inline the code.

---

```
return romanSum;
```

Well, for a performance race this is fine, but this will definitely allow invalid roman numerals. If I would see this code in a library I would certainly reprimand the person who wrote the function. Even in a race, I would definitely like invalid Roman values such as `"IC"` to be rejected; otherwise testing for those would take any performance advantage.

One ugly trick is to re-encode the resulting integer and then compare. In that case you will always have a valid input string. Yes, this does imply a performance penalty, but one that is necessary.

---

```
std::string intToRoman(int num)
```

You are recreating a `Map` *and* a `Vector` within a function. I definitely hope your compiler saves you from this, but I honestly don't think so. *Do you notice that these will never change between function calls?*

Personally I would be vary wary of using *any* kind of collections. I can easily program this *by using a single character array*, no higher level collections whatsoever. Even just calculating the hash value for the map is going to *kill* performance. It may well take more time than the whole conversion in the first place!

Note that performing calculations on current CPU's is blistering fast. De-referencing data structures generally is *not* that fast.

---

```
std::string s = mapRef.at(value);
```

Definitely can do without a method surrounding it.

---

```
 int oneSizeRomans(char c)
```

Alright, but that comment is really not necessary. You need comments in case it is not clear *what* the code is doing or *how it is doing that*. Neither do apply here.

### Hints

All in all, try to code this using **just one array containing the roman literals**. You will be surprised how fast you can search through a tiny array of just 7 elements using a simple `for` loop.

---

In Java, which is particularly C-like, I could do:

```java
int toValue(char numeral) {
    int value = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMERALS.length; i++) {
        if (NUMERALS[i] == numeral) {
            return value;
        }
        value = value * (i % 2 == 0 ? 5 : 2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can of course optimize away the `?`, this is a useful exercise in itself. Processors are even less fond of branching than of de-referencing.

---

You may use the values `0` to `9` in a switch / case statement for fast encoding to Roman literals.

---

Pre-calculate *anything* you can before going into the functions

---

Please make sure your code rejects incorrect values: correctness should always trump performance!

Comment: Yes I forgot to tell but it actually said in the leetcode problem originally that input validation as such wasnt required for roman number converting (it was assumed to be correctly formed inputs). For RomanStr-> int input was said to be (s is a valid roman numeral in the range [1, 3999].). but Definitely the correctness in terms of validation could be improved. For the case of IntToRoman, the input was said to be 1 <= num <= 3999

Comment: Alright. Please check if you have any questions about my answer, I won't have much time tomorrow. Main issue is of course `intToRoman`, I expect that this has the most problems w.r.t. speed.

Comment: Writing library quality code would of course be very commendable in leetcode I have to admit. Sometimes well voted solutions on codewars look like that could be it. But rarely is there  much input validation in these kind of small problems

Comment: Well, I can remember that I got exactly this assignment in my first year at uni, a long time ago. I'm pretty sure that they only looked at these kind of things, not performance. Took some time to get used to everything back then. Now I can program this just in half an hour. I surprised the teaching assistant with my check that simply computed the roman numerals again, but it was accepted.

Comment: yea that romanSpecials I made it to constexpr int array inside seekLargestPossible. And removed the map thing and vector thing. processToRoman could be converted easily to switch case which probably would make it faster. Process to roman could be refactored a bit so it doesnt return a new string by value... I gota admit its been a while since I did the whole char arrays thing back in C. It would take careful attention to make everything use char arrays again rather than c++ string (I suspect that c++ string usage it the main problem now)

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Maarten Bodewes' answer:

## Prefer range-`for` where possible

In `seekLargestPossible()`, you can replace the `for`-loop with this one:

```
for (auto& key: vecRef)
{
    if (key <= a)
        return key;
}
```

## Naming things

Avoid naming things after their type, instead always try to give them a name that describes what they represent. For example, `vecRef` and `mapRef` are bad names; that just repeats their type, but doesn't tell you anything about what's in the vector or map their are referencing. For `vecRef` for example, you could use `romanSpecials` as the name as that's what you are seeking in, or if you want to keep it more generic, then I suggest `values`, as `vecRef` just references a collection of values.

## Make use of STL algorithms

The standard library comes with lots of [algorithms](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) that you can use instead of writing your own. For example, `seekLargestPossible()` could be replaced with a call to [`std::lower_bound()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound):

```
int d = arabic >= 1000 ? 1000 : *std::lower_bound(romanSpecials.begin(), romanSpecials.end(), arabic, std::greater<int>());
```

Although it is perhaps overkill here.

## Avoid writing unnecessary code

The function `processToRoman` is not very useful. You can write the following directly inside `intToRoman()`:

```
std::string characters = ArabicValueToRomans.at(d);
```

## Be consistent

Why do you have a `std::map` to go from values to roman numerals, but have a function with a `switch`-statement to go from roman numerals to values? You can use the same technique for both directions.

## Don't `throw` raw strings

Instead of just `throw`ing a string when something goes wrong, I strongly recommend that you throw one of the [standard exception types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/stdexcept) instead, or possibly create your own exception class that derives from one of the standard types. It's quite simple to use them:

```
#include <stdexcept>
...
int seekLargestPossible(...)
{
    ...
    throw std::logic_error("Could not find largest possible roman numeral");
}
```

The type adds more information about the kind of error, and this allows the caller to distinguish between different errors by using different [`catch`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/try_catch) statements.

Comment: yea I think sometimes you get unlucky on the execution speed at leetcode(???). Like I managed to find the C++ solution for one guy from the discussions page and it didnt really run as fast as he claimed, consistently.  It would be intersting to see solution without any cpp strings except the return value when it gets returned as std::string the romanStr. They way I coded the solution was that first I scribbled a bit on paper and then started coding it. I didnt prove how to solve it like mathematical proof or anything like that.

Comment: I suspect that char array use and consexpr arrays (esp the romanSpecials style)  if necessary would be useful.

Answer (score -1):

### Performance

Performance code is not always good code.

Improving performance can also make the code more complex and thus harder to maintain. One must balance ones experience against the need for performance.

### Roman To Int

In this example we can combine the data (Roman numerals) with the code creating a function that reads the characters one by one and contains all the roman characters as part of the code. This lets use conditional search roman numerals depending on the one we have just encountered.

We also know that only `M` `C` and `X` will be repeated so we check for repeats only after finding one of them.

Tracking the string read position can also be ignored when the remaining value is <= 9 (<= IX). That means we do lose track of just how many digits are read, but I don't see that is a requirement in this case.

### Example 2

The result is not pretty

Be careful with the pointer to i

```
unsigned romanValueAt(unsigned *i, std::string s) {
    unsigned val;
    switch (s[(*i)++]) {
        case 'D': return 500;
        case 'L': return 50;
        case 'I':
            switch (s[(*i)++]) {
                case 'X': return 9;
                case 'V': return 4;
                case 'I': 
                    if (s[(*i)++] == 'I') { return 3; }
                    else { return 2; }
                default: { return 1; }              
            }
        case 'V': {
            if (s[(*i)++] == 'I') {
                if (s[(*i)++] == 'I') {
                    if (s[(*i)++] != 'I') { return 7; } /* Warning i could be past
                    return 8;                              end of string */
                } 
                return 6;
            } 
            return 5;
        }
        case 'M': {
            val = 1000;
            while (s[(*i)++] == 'M') { val += 1000; }
            (*i)--;
            return val;
        }
        case 'C':
            switch (s[*i]) {
                case 'M': { (*i)++; return 900; }
                case 'D': { (*i)++; return 400; }
                default: {
                    val = 100;
                    while (s[(*i)++] == 'C') { val += 100; }
                    (*i)--;
                    return val;
                }
            }
        case 'X':
            switch (s[*i]) {
                case 'C': { (*i)++; return 90; }
                case 'L': { (*i)++; return 40; }
                default: {
                    val = 10;
                    while (s[(*i)++] == 'X') { val += 10; }
                    (*i)--;
                    return val;
                }               
            }
    }
    return 0;
}
unsigned romanToUint(std::string roman) {
    unsigned value = 0, i = 0, len = roman.length();
    while (i < len) { value += romanValueAt(&i, roman); }
    return value;
}
```

### Int to Roman

Converting from number to roman also has some room for optimizations.

#### `log10` to count digits

We can use the 'log10' of a number to quickly know how many digits it contains, That means we don't need to wast time checking the value against higher values than needed.

#### Divide for sequences

For the sequences eg `XXX` or `MMXXX` we can also do them in one step if we divide by the roman value we get the number of repeats. EG 3992 / 1000 = 3 (as int) which is the number of `M` it contains `MMMCMXCII`

#### Use hash map for large data sets

Avoid using `map` as each time you lookup an item it needs to run a hash function and for small maps the overhead outweighs any time complexity gain.

#### Example 2

In this case you only need to iterate at max 9 values, everything else is just direct array indexing. Values under 10 are looked up directly.

```
#include <math.h> 
std::string UintToRoman(unsigned value) {
    const std::string digits[9] = {"I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", "VII", "VIII", "IX"};
    const std::string copies[9][2] = {{"MM", "MMM"},{},{},{},{"CC","CCC"},{},{},{},{"XX","XXX"}};
    const std::string romB[9] = {"M", "CM", "D", "CD", "C", "XC", "L", "XL", "X"};
    const unsigned rom[9] = {1000, 900, 500, 400, 100, 90, 50, 40, 10};
    const unsigned starts[4] = {9, 5, 1, 0}; 
   
    std::string res = "";
    unsigned i = starts[(unsigned) log10((double) value)];
    while (i < 9 && value >= 10) {
        const unsigned v = rom[i];
        if (value >= v) {
            const int c = value / v;
            value -= c * v;
            res += c == 1 ? romB[i] : copies[i][c - 2];
        }
        i++;
    }
    return  value > 0 ? res + digits[value - 1] : res;
}
```

### Improvements

Do the above example provide an performance benefit. I am unsure as I am not a member of leetcode so have no environment to compare against.

There are also many more ways to improve the examples.

### Constraints

Roman numerals have a very limited range 1 to 3999. The examples give in the answer are only valid to this range.

It is assumed inputs are correctly formatted and within range.